# AngularJS - showing placeholder if image doesn't exist

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of items in some search results, some items have images, others do not.  For those those items that do not have images I want to show a placeholder.

**What would be the best approach to this?**
 I am currently trying to do it with a function  (imageURL) and passing it the image details for the current item in the loop/repeat.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="listing in searchResults.listings">
                <div class="item item-image">
                    <img src="{{::searchResults.imageURL(listing._id,listing._source.filename1)}}">
                </div>
                .....
```

Inside the controller (controller as SearchResults):

```
self = this;
.....
self.imageURL = function(listing_id, listing_filename) {

        if (angular.isUndefined(listing_id) || angular.isUndefined(listing_filename)) { //No image
            return placeholderImage; //We want to show placeholderImage
        }
        return self.imageURL + listing_id + "/" + listing_filename; //Show the image

    };
```

I will also be using a lazy loader directive at a later point, so will not be using the "src" attribute directly at that time.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you like what you have?

Comment: Scratch that, I made a silly mistake, my function name was the same as a variable name within the controller and that variable was used within the function, all seems fine now.. silly billy.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a directive that replaces the `src` attribute, like `ng-src` does, and internally handles the logic you currently have in your `imageURL` function.

If the directive is named `image-url` then the markup would look something like this:

```
<img image-url="listing">
```

And your directive would look something like this:

```
app.directive('imageUrl', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            imageUrl: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var imageUrl;
            if (angular.isUndefined(scope.listing._id) || angular.isUndefined(scope.listing._source.filename1)) { //No image
                imageUrl = placeholderImage; //We want to show placeholderImage
            }
            else {
                imageUrl = "/" + scope.listing._id + "/" + scope.listing._source.filename1; // Set the src attribute
            }
            element.attr("src", imageUrl); // Set the src attribute
        }
    };
});
```

You really don't want to bind directly to the `src` attribute for reasons described in the [ngSrc documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of a directive rather than function.

Comment: Yeah, a directive really is the cleanest, most "Angular" way to do what you want to do. By the way, I just noticed that I missed one of the returns from your original code, so I've updated the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-src` rather than `src`.

From [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc);

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a `src` attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   `{{hash}}` until Angular replaces the expression inside `{{hash}}`. The
>   `ngSrc` directive solves this problem.